# 4 Class Classification - Machine Learning Model

Tags: machine-learning, classification, supervised-learning

I have a data set which contains nearly **150** features and **60k** data. And my target feature is continuous variable represents hours. I divided this period into 4 categories of user engagement (4 ranges of hours). Implement `GA` with `SVM`, `GA` with logistic regression, Random forest, `GA` with `KNN` with suitable normalization of data wherever required. Used `GA` for best feature subset selection.

All the algorithms gave similar results of around `46%` accuracy ( for nearly balanced test set).

**Note:** Training is also done on a balanced data set. I am wondering where am I gone wrong?

I believe I went wrong somewhere in input to target mapping. Could anyone please confirm that categorization of the continuous target variable (hrs) into 4 sets are reasonable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, binning a continuous variable so that in can take discrete values is reasonable, as long as you are OK with transforming this regression problem into a classification one.

Just note that when dealing with a balanced 4-class classification problem, if an algorithm hadn't learnt anything and was predicting randomly it would achieve a 25% accuracy. Your results indicate that the algorithms are at least learning **something**. It might just be a **very difficult task** to solve, in that the features might have little to no correlation with the output variable.

I'd suggest trying out more algorithms with and without GA.